# child element padding pushes it down below the parent div

Tags: html

I have a div with a class parent and a p nested inside the parent. styling the parent to

```
.parent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
   background: red;
}
```

and child element to

```
.parent p {
   padding-top: 50%;
}
```

causes the child element to go below the parent div. 
The suppose the p paragraph is supposed to add a 50% padding above it, thereby sitting at the center of the parent div. Even when i replace the padding with a margin-top, it still creates same weird result.

Comment: can you post your Html ?

Comment: why the C tag though?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, that `padding-top: 50%` is getting 50% of the width, not the height of the container.
What you're after would be most easily achieved by turning your div into a flexbox.

Example:

```css
.parent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 150px;
   background: red;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <p>Example Text</p>
</div>
```

If you wanted the text to be centred horizontally as well, you could add `justify-content: center;` to the .parent class.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I understand that flexbox can do the job but I was wandering why using margin top behaves this way. I went further with a little experiment and notice that reducing the parent width to 60%, brings the child element closer to the parent and reducing it more to 31% makes the child element centered on the parent. It seems like the width of the parent is affecting the child margin top. Please help me with some explanation why its so, Thanks